# How can I force namespace prefix usage?

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I'm trying to consume a SOAP Webservice, but the WSDL is kind of broken, so I have to do some customization to [`node-soap`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap).

The ideal SOAP Envelope that I would like to have would be this one:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <getImagesDefinition xmlns="http://services.example.com/"/>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

So far this is the `nodejs` code I have to invoke the service:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://www.example.com/services/imagesizes?wsdl';

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {

    client.setEndpoint('http://www.example.com/services/imagesizes');
    client.getImagesDefinition(null, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
    console.log(client.lastRequest)

});
```

I had to set the endpoint manually because it is broken in the `WSDL` file

The envelope I get when printing `client.lastRequest` is this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
               xmlns:tns="http://services.example.com/">
    <soap:Body>
        <getImagesDefinition />
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I know that if I can force the namespace prefix on the body to have `<tns:getImagesDefinition />` instead of `<getImagesDefinition />` the request works perfectly.

Is there any way for me to force it?

I read the documentation saying that `tns` is a default ignored namespace, so I tried to change that by doing this:

```
var options = {
    ignoredNamespaces: {
        namespaces: [],
        override: true
    }
}
```

and sending that object to the `soap.createClient` method, but I see no difference on the Envelope.

Is there anyway for me to force this? or get to the ideal SOAP Envelope?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this exact problem and for me, the fix was to override the ignoredNamespaces - to remove 'tns' as an ignored namespace.

```
var options = { 
  ignoredNamespaces: {
    namespaces: ['targetNamespace', 'typedNamespace'],
    override: true
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why it didn't work for you, but maybe there was a bug in the library that has since been fixed. Or maybe because you didn't include any namespaces, but rather an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/issues/537) thread discussing the same issue at github:

And especially
 https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/issues/537#issuecomment-72041420

Comment: Temporary fix: Change line 1047 in wsdl.js to: `WSDL.prototype.ignoredNamespaces = ['targetNamespace', 'typedNamespace'];`

Comment: That link is broken. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This is why answers that only contain links are not helpful